# Run a automatic proof checking program in Lean from terminal

Tags: lean

On Lean's official tutorials, I have seen how to play with Lean programs in Vscode and Emacs. I would like to know how to run a Lean from terminal. For example, say I wrote a program to check there are infinitely many prime numbers as `infinite_primes.lean` and I would like to run it by executing

```
lean infinite_primes.lean
```

in the terminal. But this option does not seem to be available.

Comment: There's a command `lean --run` (which I've never used until just now).

You can try this "Hello world" example. It seems to only work if the return type of `main` is `io something`          
```lean
import system.io

def main : io unit :=
do io.put_str "Hello world", return ()
```

Comment: You'll get a better response than this if you ask at [Zulip](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/)